# How did I manage to upvote my own answer!

Tags: support, up-votes

I do check my old answers from time to time, and I was surprised when I checked [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20207/why-are-airline-passengers-asked-to-lift-up-window-shades-during-takeoff-and-lan/20208#20208), I found it upvoted by me! I checked other answers I found none so far. I closed the browser and reopened it just to make sure and yes it still there. I tried to upvote other answers by me and I couldn't of course. I did not remove the upvote until now, it looks cool actually.

**How?**

[image]

Comment: Lol SE is sure some wonderland. (I'm not Alice though) This one was something new! +1

Comment: lol, sock exposed.

Comment: @shadow LOL, no socks cousin..

Comment: *cough* you might have missed the answer on this question (I see you didn't post any comment on it). I'm not judging or anything since it's old water under the bridge now, but it perfectly explains how it's possible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that was not the case, it was similar anyway, I think I have an explanation but for now I am too sleepy.. I will post an answer after morning coffee..

Comment: OK, looking forward to read it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I answered it :)

Comment: Hi @NeanDerThal, I'm not English native speaker. What does sock mean in this context?

Answer (score 9):

That post couldn't possibly be answered with your current account so I suspect your account got merged with an other one.

This is what I get from [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/301891):

The post was created on Sep, 2nd 2013 by an owner that had an displayname of *user1712*
Your account with id 10051 was created on Jan, 21th, 2014 (displayname *MeNoTalk*)

[Here is a comment from jan, 28th 2014](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21475/do-argentinian-atms-only-accept-4-digit-pins#comment39842_21475)  directed at user1712 that I assume is a response to [this comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21475/do-argentinian-atms-only-accept-4-digit-pins#comment37549_21475) from Dec, 16th, 2013. That is before your current account existed.

On your [meta profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4zYG.png)  it is even more clear that the timeline of your posts don't match with how long your account exist.

I assume you voted with your current account (10051) on the answer of the now merged account. Due to the merge it now looks like you voted on your own post.

Comment: Wow! Lets suspend him for 'voting irregularities' ;)

Comment: Usually votes between merged accounts are invalidated as part of the merge, so this is peculiar.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: "Usually". Hmmm... Seems to be a bug when attaching posts back to an account as described in the second answer.

Answer (score 4):

@rene's answer made me realize how I managed to upvote my own answer, it could have not been a merge for two *active* accounts because as mentioned by @Monica Cellio votes are invalidated in merges, so no sock.

What happened is I was on a rage, and asked to delete my account, it was deleted. Two or three weeks later I registered a new account and a few more weeks later I asked support to attach my old posts to my new account, they were helpful and accepted my request (which I sincerely thank them for) . I must during this time upvoted my own answer which was technically not mine at that moment. I guess attaching questions back to a user does not invalidate votes. That's it.

I apologize for the constant headache I always cause :)

Comment: So you still upvoted your own answer. That is how it went at that time. (Although you didn't gain the rep directly since the accounts weren't attached at that time). I am still curious why you did that in the first place.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I must have seen my answer and went like "wow that's a good answer" and upvoted it :D

Comment: I guess so... ;)

Comment: Inactive/Raging sock is still a sock... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am trying to unvote, I can't ;)